# BaseAdapter class not working - Android

Tags: json, class, android-listview, android-asynctask, baseadapter

I have a Asynctask that gathers comments through a JSON method. It then places the comments into a String[] which is placed into a listView, the problem is the class that extends BaseAdapter gives me an error and wont let me use it? Number is suppose to be a string! Not an int. Here is my current code,

```
    class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {
             private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();


            } 

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

            } 

            protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {


                JSONObject json2 = CollectComments.collectComments(usernameforcomments, offsetNumber);


                    return json2;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                try {  
                    if (json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) { 
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                        String res2 = json2.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                        if(Integer.parseInt(res2) == 1){ 
                             l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


                            JSONArray commentArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_COMMENT);
                            final String comments[] = new String[commentArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<commentArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                comments[i] = commentArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray numberArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_NUMBER);
                            String numbers[] = new String[numberArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<numberArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                numbers[i] = numberArray.getString(i);
                            }
                            JSONArray usernameArray = json2.getJSONArray(KEY_USERNAME);
                            String usernames[] = new String[usernameArray.length()];
                            for ( int i=0; i<usernameArray.length(); i++ ) {
                                usernames[i] = usernameArray.getString(i);
                            }


                            l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(comments,numbers,usernames));


                            class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
                                String[] Comment, Username, number ;


                                dataListAdapter() {
                                    Comment = null;
                                    Username = null;
                                    number = null;
                                }

                                public dataListAdapter(String[] text, String[] text1,String[] text3) {
                                    Comment = text;
                                    Username = text1;
                                    number = text3;

                                }

                                public int getCount() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return Comment.length;
                                }

                                public Object getItem(int arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return null;
                                }

                                public long getItemId(int position) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    return position;
                                }

                                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                                    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                                    View row;
                                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                                    TextView listComment, listnumber, listUsername;

                                    listComment = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
                                    listnumber = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
                                    listUsername=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);
                                    listComment.setText(Comment[position]);
                                    listnumber.setText(number[position]);
                                    listUsername.setText(Username[position]);

                                    return (row);
                                }
                            }









                            }//end if key is == 1
                        else{
                            // Error in registration
                            registerErrorMsg.setText(json2.getString(KEY_ERROR_MSG));
                        }//end else
                    }//end if
                } //end try

                catch (JSONException e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }//end catch    
            }
        }


        new loadComments().execute();
```

I get the error

```
    The type dataListAdapter must implement the inherited abstract method Adapter.getView(int, View, ViewGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter are missing @Override annotation before methods getView, getCount, getItem, getItemId.

And I suggest you to have you adapter class outside of AsyncTask class method. Becouse you code is really unreadable. It shold look like this:

```
class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {
    // code here
}

class DataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // code here
}
```

And classes should always start with uppercase (LoadComments class no loadComments) and variables always with lowercase (String name no String Name). Maybe I shouldn't write it here but it will be usefull for you, to make you code easier to read :)

Comment: But it has to be inside of the asynctask because the asynctask is what gets the Strings?

Comment: You pass initial data (String[] Comment, Username, number) to adapter through constructor, so no need to have adapter class in async task method.

Comment: How do I pass the data to the adapter?